# How do I pass this JSON data to an autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, json

Special thanks to Raúl Monge for posting a fully working code for me.

My problem was getting JSON data from a file.json and using this data to autocomplete search on it with JavaScript. The code that finaly got it working for me is the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arrayAutocomplete = new Array();
    $.getJSON('json/telefoonnummers.json', function(json) {         
    $.each(json.personen.persoon,function(index, value){
            arrayAutocomplete[index] = new Array();
            arrayAutocomplete[index]['label'] = value.naam+" - "+value.telefoonnummer;
        });
        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({source: arrayAutocomplete});
    });      
});
```

This is the html:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="search" />       
</div>
```

And this has to be included in the head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thanks stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEW EDIT CODE WORKING:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arrayAutocomplete = new Array();
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {         
       $.each(json.persons.person,function(index, value){
            arrayAutocomplete[index] = new Array();
            arrayAutocomplete[index]['label'] = value.name;
            arrayAutocomplete[index]['value'] = value.phoneno;
        });
        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({source: arrayAutocomplete});
    });      
});
</script>
```

Add this in head

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is the html

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="search" />       
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried to implement this but my autocomplete function is not showing any results, what might cause this? edited my code, check it out.

Comment: Just update the code and now it's working, if you want display the name when u click in just change the array value "value.phoneno" for "value.name"

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. This is awesome! One last thing, is there a way to add the phone no to a result? like: Kevin - 201 instead of just the name?  

EDIT: GOT IT! just added the phoneno value to the label, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
 var data = [
    "Aragorn",
    "Arwen",
    ....
    ];
```

since all of those data are labels?

Comment: check all the dependencies especially the jquery

Comment: Okay, let me look into that. Thx:)

Answer (score 0):

[**There you go**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/GyA5j/1/)

A working example with the data structure you have.
Just initialize the autocomplete once the JSON is loaded & the data is formatted.

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document ready is within your function.
Try to write your function outside of your document ready.
Then write your document ready to call your function.
Some something like this:

```
function loadJson() {                               
   //alert("Whoohoo, you called the loadJson function!"); //uncomment for testing
   var mycontainer = [];
   $.getJSON( "data.json" , function(data) {
       //alert(data) //uncomment for testing
       $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
          //alert("key: "+key+" | val: "+val); //uncomment for testing
          array.push([key , val]);
       });

   });
   return mycontainer;

}

$(document).ready(function(){                   
   //alert("Boojah! jQuery library loaded!"); //uncomment for testing
   var content = loadJson();

   dosomethingwitharray(content);

});
```

Hope this helps!

Also make sure you have jQuery included in your head `( <head> </head> )`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And add your javascript at the end of your body `( <body> </body> )`.

To test if jquery does it's job try this:

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <title>getting started with jquery</title>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>my page</h1>
       <p>this paragraph contains some text.</p>

       <!-- javascript at end -->
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

             //show a dialog, confirming when the document is loaded and jquery is used.
             alert("boojah, jquery called the document ready function");

             //do something with jquery, for example, modify the dom
             $("p").append('<br /> i am able to modify the dom with the help of jquery and added this line, i am awesome.');

          }); 
       </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

*PS. Uncomment alerts for testing stuff, so you can test what happens. If you have space in your document i suggest using $.append to an div that log's all action's so you can see exactly what's going on because alert's in a loop like the .each are quite annoying! more about append: http://api.jquery.com/append/*

Comment: I tried to implement this, this is also not giving me any results. When I enter a search criteria it just stays blank. I'm not sure why but when I uncomment the comments I dont get any alerts either. Sorry I'm really new to JS..

Comment: You have jquery included within your head? getJson, each and document ready are jquery functions. I will update my answer, explaining it a little.

Comment: Done. An example to test jquery, if the second example above. Just copy/paste that second example and start adding more and more code. Testing it bit by bit, until you get the hang of it! Incase this still doesn't work, you probably have javascript disabled in your browser.